# Ctrl+Alt+T not working to open Terminal in WSL

Tags: shortcut-keys, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 a few days ago from the Microsoft App Store.

I'm trying to carry out an exercise which requires me opening the Terminal.

I was instructed to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but this doesn't work at all. Every time I use it, it makes a weird error-like sound.

This is  my first time trying to open the Terminal. 
How do I fix this?

Comment: You can open it by searching for it and clicking like any other app. Why the keyboard shortcut isn't working I have no idea.

Comment: Let's see if GNOME Terminal works at all. Does `Alt`+`F2` followed by `gnome-terminal` followed by `Enter` work?

Comment: Hey, I tried the Alt + F2 followed by gnome-terminal then enter. It did not work. Every time I used Alt + F2, a Q came up.

Comment: @Chai and Gabriela, turns out OP is using WSL

Comment: I simply setup a Windows Desktop Icon to click for the terminal. But for your needs this might be helpful: https://www.howtogeek.com/270810/how-to-quickly-launch-a-bash-shell-from-windows-10s-file-explorer/ This is almost a Windows Shortcut key question though...

Answer (score 5):

By default that is the shortcut, but it might happen that someone have redefined the same.

For this, go to **Settings→Devices→Keyboard** and redefine or reset to default by clicking on **✕**(if previously redefined) beside it the shortcut.

[image: Keyboard settings]

#### Update:

The above works with **Ubuntu OS**. Since the OP is using WSL, there are two ways to launch Ubuntu Terminal:

- **Command Prompt**: Command prompt can be launched from Start or can be run by using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> an typing `cmd`. In command prompt , you need to write `ubuntu` or `ubuntu1604` or `ubuntu1804` depending on the version you've downloaded.
- **Using Ubuntu App**: You can define its shortcut using app settings and assign it shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

***But that makes it a Windows question.***
For this read:
[How to Create Keyboard Shortcuts in Windows 10](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/create-keyboard-shortcuts-windows-10)